# Apply own app integrated with google apps

Tags: google-apps, google-account

I want to develop an web app which could be integrated into Google app account(in other word it should be appear in google app service panel),I dont want to realize it via marketplace and Google engine, is there any ways out there?Thx~

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean by "I dont want to realize it via marketplace and Google engine"?

Comment: normally we could apply an autonomous development app to our google app account,so that we could have possibility to switch on/off this app or other operations.As far as I know there are two ways to realize: Google markeplace and GAE

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Google Apps Extensions Console](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/extensions-console/) and make the app available only on your domain.